# Basic email app is giving cannot convert type object error

Tags: c#

I want to create a small app to automate some emails that i need sending. I have followed a guide but for some reason its not working even though I have followed it as closely as i can.

So far i have just created a form with a button on it that i just want to create the simple email first and take it from there.

However I am getting an error on the below part

```
MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem"

Any idea what i am doing wrong? The full code is below.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Outlookapp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;

namespace Auto_Email
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                      
            Outlookapp app = new Outlookapp();
            MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mailItem.Subject = "This is the subject";
            mailItem.HTMLBody = "Body goes here";
            mailItem.Display(false);   

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What Outlookapp.CreateItem method returns? Seems it is returning object and not MailItem instance ...

Comment: ```public object CreateItem (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType ItemType);```

Comment: @puko im not sure, is there a way i can test to find out what it is returning?

Comment: @Yippiekaiaii either using the hints provided by most IDEs or by referring to the documentation. but the error message already tells you its type object

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot implicitly convert a type, explicitly cast it (if you know for sure that it's the correct type)

```
MailItem mailItem = (MailItem)app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

or better

```
MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem) as MailItem;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator